# Generating Cartesian coordinates of each atom in protein chain from the internal coordinates using python or some software

Tags: biochemistry, bioinformatics, protein-structure, structural-biology, computational-model

I am trying to compute Cartesian coordinates of backbone atoms and side-chain atoms (C beta alone) for a given set of internal coordinates (bond lengths, bond angles and dihedral angles) I have written a code for the backbone alone (i.e) to construct cartesian coordinates of each atom in backbone from the respective internal coordinates(without side chains). However I got to know that this can be done in a software (maybe in PyMol or VMD). I am completely a beginner in this field of biochemistry/bioinformatics/biophysics. Does it really possible to do this in software like PYMOL/VMD? I'll be very happy if I can do this in python itself. I want to generate cartesian coordinate of a given tetrapeptide for all possible Ramachandran angles (within the allowed region)

Comment: Do you have the structure of the tetrapeptide provided or you want to run a simulation and get all the possible dihedral angles (they are not called Ramachandran angles)?.

Comment: No, I have just bond angles, bond lengths (standard values). Now for a given set of dihedral angles (Ramachandran angles) for tetrapeptide I need to generate the cartesian coordinates. I need to simulate the structure. I don't want the minimum energy structure. I just want to get the structure of tetrapeptide for a given set of internal coordinates ). @RoniSaiba

Comment: VMD by itself can't generate MD trajectories. You will need some other software like NAMD or the like to do so. However, once you have a trajectory, you can write a script (in Tcl) for VMD which will give you the cartesian coordinates of the atoms in a txt file which you can then process in python, R etc. [Here](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Training/Tutorials/gpu/gpu-tutorial.pdf) is a Tutorial on how to use NAMD and VMD to get the job done. You will have to first make a .PDB of your tetrapeptide. You can use Avogadro to do that.

Comment: Is it a biology or bioinformatics STACK forum question ??? It could be also a chemistry one if talking about molecular dinamics ?? A penny for your thoughts

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Biopython](https://biopython.org/)

There are specific questions about the specific internal coordinates on Bioinformatics forum i.e. :

https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/18849/help-using-biopythons-ic-chain-functionality-for-getting-protein-3d-coordinates

or

https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/19570/read-pdb-file-extract-dihedral-angles-modify-dihedral-angles-reconstruct-cart/19597#comment28645_19597